# Getters and setters for java.sql.date

Tags: java, date, deprecated, getter-setter

I want to get/set year, month and day of a Date object but eclipse says that it is deprecated and I get a `NullPointerException` when I execute the code (to be honest I am not sure if I get the exception because of this but it seems like that).

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
public TSTLocalDate dateToTSTLocalDate(Date date) {     

    this.calenderDate.year = date.getYear();            
    this.calenderDate.month = date.getMonth();          
    this.calenderDate.day = date.getDay();

    return this.calenderDate;
}
```

My goal, in the end, is to convert `Date` to `Datetype` which I have created on my own.

Are there other ways to get/set Date?

EDIT: Here is the exception but it refers to some other things in the code and I can't post everything here:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ferdec.tst.tstgui.domain.TSTHoliday.dateToTSTLocalDate(TSTHoliday.java:145)
at com.ferdec.tst.tstgui.domain.TSTHoliday.<init>(TSTHoliday.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.ferdec.tst.tstgui.view.StaticDataHandlerFactory$5.handle(StaticDataHandlerFactory.java:909)
at com.ferdec.tst.tstgui.view.StaticDataHandlerFactory$5.handle(StaticDataHandlerFactory.java:1)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: please post the exception trowed.

Comment: There are two possibilities of *this code* throwing a `NullPointerException`: `date` is `null` or `this.calendarDate` is `null`. Why have you created your own date class when there is `java.time`? Do you use an older version of Java? I think the error comes from somewhere else, but figuring out the source is your task.

Comment: @deHaar I got the task to convert Date to our own date class in a program which I do not really know since it is very complex, so sadly I do not know in details why to do that. Sorry

Comment: My guess is you have been given the task to find out yourself how difficult it is to implement a custom class representing a date. Is that a school/university task or a real business task you were given at work?

Comment: @deHaar It is a real business task at work but I am still a junior developer (part-time) who is still studying so you could be right

Comment: Well, you could somehow cheat and build up a class that uses classes from `java.time` internally. I don't know the exact requirements, so don't take that as an advice, it is just a (kind of dirty) possibility of solving the task.

Comment: Those methods are deprecated for a reason.  A java.util.Date is the number of milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.  If a Date represents 01:00 AM UTC on January 1 2019, what do `getYear()`, `getMonth()`, and `getDay()` return?  In my timezone, it’s December 31 2018.  You cannot reliably obtain calendar information without a timezone.  You’re better off [converting your Date to a LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate%28%29).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Objects.requireNonNull`

As others noted, you should [check that incoming argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T,java.lang.String)) is not null.

```
public TSTLocalDate dateToTSTLocalDate(Date date) {     
    Objects.requireNonNull( date , "Opps, received a NULL rather than a Date object. Message # e99b92a3-da0b-419b-9f93-8cfee36a757b." ) ;
…
```

You have other problems.

## Time zone

The `Date` represents a moment in UTC. Determining a date requires a time zone. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone.

But your code ignores this crucial issue of time zone. The `Calendar` class (actually `GregorianCalendar`) implicitly uses the JVM’s current default time zone when you neglect to provide one. So your results may vary. Better to always specify explicitly your desired/expected time zone.

## *java.time*

Another problem: You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

Convert your `java.util.Date` to `Instant`, both classes representing a moment in UTC.

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant() ;
```

Specify your desired/expected zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Extract the date-only portion, without time-of-day, and without time zone.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;
```

You can interrogate the `LocalDate` for its year, month, and day.

You can generate strings in various formats representing the value of the `LocalDate` by using `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

Answer (score 1):

On the 2nd line in the exception, there is probably the exact line in which it happens:

> TSTHoliday.dateToTSTLocalDate(TSTHoliday.java:**145**)

called by

> TSTHoliday.java:**42**

Check if the `date` object passed to this method is null, something like this:

```
TSTLocalDate tSTLocalDate;
if(date != null) {
    tSTLocalDate = dateToTSTLocalDate(date);
}
```

And in the method you may add a check for null:

```
public TSTLocalDate dateToTSTLocalDate(Date date) {     

    if(date == null) {
        Log.d("TAGLOG", "Error date null in dateToTSTLocalDate");
    }
    else {
        this.calenderDate.year = date.getYear();            
        this.calenderDate.month = date.getMonth();          
        this.calenderDate.day = date.getDay();
    }

    return this.calenderDate;
}
```

Comment: This is helpful! That row is `this.calenderDate.day = date.getDay();`